# Sharepoint List Calculated field - formula help!

Tags: list, calculated-column-formula

I have this formula working fine, but when field VD (which is a date field) is empty, it adds a funny date to it.  How can I get it to us the VD field when populated, but if its empty just display TBC or NULL or something like that.

```
=CONCATENATE([ID],"|",[VT],"|",TEXT([VD],"dd/mm/yyyy"),"|",[Spec],"|",[Hub],"|",[Name])
```

help is appreciated :-)

Answer (score 4):

Check for blank values:
i.e.

```
 (IF(ISBLANK([VD]),"",TEXT([VD],"dd/mm/yyyy")))

 =CONCATENATE([ItemID],"|",[VT],"|",(IF(ISBLANK([VD]),"",TEXT([VD],"dd/mm/yyyy"))),"|",[Spec],"|",[Hub],"|",[Name])
```

Comment: @Davejones please don't forget to set the answer as accepted it's the true sign beside the answer!